# Different EMA (Exponential Moving Average) than on Binance

Tags: java, api, moving-average, binance, tradingview-api

I am writing a Java program by using the [Binance JAVA API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/master/src/test/java/com/binance/api/examples/CandlesticksCacheExample.java) to retrieve the 1-minute interval candelsticks of a trading pair. Using [this](https://github.com/markusaksli/TradeBot/blob/master/src/main/java/indicators/EMA.java) Java class, I want to calculate the EMA (Exponential Moving Average) of the past 10 days.

The Binance JAVA API websocket implementation gets the latest depth events, which also contains the current closing price that I use to update the EMA calculation by calling the `EMA#update` method.

However, I notice that the EMA showing on the Binance's graph, does not correspond to the ones I get from my code. Also, I notice that the values need some time to 'settle' before giving (somewhat) same values compared to those shown on Binance.

[image: Output of the program]

[image: Values on Binance]

On TradingView I found [a formula](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000592270-exponential-moving-average/) to calculate the EMA (that shows the same EMA value as on Binance), but that is different than the one used in the EMA class. However, even when using this formula, the values are very different than the one on Binance.

Could someone help me figure out what the issue is and how to obtain the same values?

**UPDATE 1: code provided**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiClientFactory;
import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiRestClient;
import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiWebSocketClient;
import com.binance.api.client.domain.market.Candlestick;
import com.binance.api.client.domain.market.CandlestickInterval;
import core.util.text.DecimalFormat;
import core.util.text.StringUtil;

public class test_003
{
  private Map<Long, Candlestick> candlesticksCache = new TreeMap<>();

  private EMA EMA_10;
  private EMA EMA_20;

  public static void main(String[] pArgs)
  {
    new test_003();
  }

  private test_003()
  {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

    candlesticksCacheExample("ADAUSDT", CandlestickInterval.ONE_MINUTE);
  }

  private void candlesticksCacheExample(String symbol, CandlestickInterval interval)
  {
    initializeCandlestickCache(symbol, interval);

    startCandlestickEventStreaming(symbol, interval);
  }

  private void initializeCandlestickCache(String symbol, CandlestickInterval interval)
  {
    BinanceApiClientFactory factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance();
    BinanceApiRestClient client = factory.newRestClient();

    List<Candlestick> candlestickBars_10 = client.getCandlestickBars(symbol.toUpperCase(), interval, Integer.valueOf(11), null, null);
    List<Candlestick> candlestickBars_20 = client.getCandlestickBars(symbol.toUpperCase(), interval, Integer.valueOf(21), null, null);

    List<Double> closingPriceList_10 = candlestickBars_10.stream().map(c -> Double.valueOf(c.getClose())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Double> closingPriceList_20 = candlestickBars_20.stream().map(c -> Double.valueOf(c.getClose())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    EMA_10 = new EMA(closingPriceList_10, Integer.valueOf(10));
    EMA_20 = new EMA(closingPriceList_20, Integer.valueOf(20));
  }

  private void startCandlestickEventStreaming(String symbol, CandlestickInterval interval)
  {
    BinanceApiClientFactory factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance();
    BinanceApiWebSocketClient client = factory.newWebSocketClient();

    client.onCandlestickEvent(symbol.toLowerCase(), interval, response -> {
      Long openTime = response.getOpenTime();
      Candlestick updateCandlestick = candlesticksCache.get(openTime);
      if (updateCandlestick == null)
      {
        // new candlestick
        updateCandlestick = new Candlestick();
      }

      // update candlestick with the stream data
      updateCandlestick.setOpenTime(response.getOpenTime());
      updateCandlestick.setOpen(response.getOpen());
      updateCandlestick.setLow(response.getLow());
      updateCandlestick.setHigh(response.getHigh());
      updateCandlestick.setClose(response.getClose());
      updateCandlestick.setCloseTime(response.getCloseTime());
      updateCandlestick.setVolume(response.getVolume());
      updateCandlestick.setNumberOfTrades(response.getNumberOfTrades());
      updateCandlestick.setQuoteAssetVolume(response.getQuoteAssetVolume());
      updateCandlestick.setTakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume(response.getTakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume());
      updateCandlestick.setTakerBuyBaseAssetVolume(response.getTakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume());

      // Store the updated candlestick in the cache
      candlesticksCache.put(openTime, updateCandlestick);

      double closingPrice = Double.valueOf(updateCandlestick.getClose());

      EMA_10.update(closingPrice);
      EMA_20.update(closingPrice);

      System.out.println(StringUtil.replacePlaceholders("Closing price: %1 | EMA(10): %2 - EMA(20): %3", response.getClose(),
                                                        DecimalFormat.format(EMA_10.get(), "#.#####"),
                                                        DecimalFormat.format(EMA_20.get(), "#.#####")));
    });
  }

  public class EMA
  {

    private double currentEMA;
    private final int period;
    private final double multiplier;
    private final List<Double> EMAhistory;
    private final boolean historyNeeded;
    private String fileName;


    public EMA(List<Double> closingPrices, int period)
    {
      this(closingPrices, period, false);
    }

    public EMA(List<Double> closingPrices, int period, boolean historyNeeded)
    {
      currentEMA = 0;
      this.period = period;
      this.historyNeeded = historyNeeded;
      this.multiplier = 2.0 / (double) (period + 1);
      this.EMAhistory = new ArrayList<>();
      init(closingPrices);
    }

    public double get()
    {
      return currentEMA;
    }

    public double getTemp(double newPrice)
    {
      return (newPrice - currentEMA) * multiplier + currentEMA;
    }

    public void init(List<Double> closingPrices)
    {
      if (period > closingPrices.size()) return;

      //Initial SMA
      for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
      {
        currentEMA += closingPrices.get(i);
      }

      currentEMA = currentEMA / (double) period;
      if (historyNeeded) EMAhistory.add(currentEMA);
      //Dont use latest unclosed candle;
      for (int i = period; i < closingPrices.size() - 1; i++)
      {
        update(closingPrices.get(i));
      }
    }

    public void update(double newPrice)
    {
      // EMA = (Close - EMA(previousBar)) * multiplier + EMA(previousBar)
      currentEMA = (newPrice - currentEMA) * multiplier + currentEMA;

      if (historyNeeded) EMAhistory.add(currentEMA);
    }

    public int check(double newPrice)
    {
      return 0;
    }

    public String getExplanation()
    {
      return null;
    }

    public List<Double> getEMAhistory()
    {
      return EMAhistory;
    }

    public int getPeriod()
    {
      return period;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: I think you can cross check your outcome with open source library like https://www.ta-lib.org/hdr_dev.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I still get slight differences in EMA values. Can you please help me more by running my code?

Comment: Do you use enough history data for ema calculation? It should be around 3x of the ema's lookback to stabilize the value. For example if ema got a length of 10, you would receive the first value on the 10th candle, but ema would be considered 'stable' only around the 30th candle.

Comment: @e2e4 I cranked up the historical data to the max limit that Binance API sends back, that is a 1000 candlesticks for 1minute interval. When running my program, the values are spot on identical to the ones Binance is showing. But after 30seconds, the values differ slightly and after a minute or 2, they differ a lot (see image in my last update)

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I am trying 2nd day now.. Found everyavailable formula, tried different wights, I can never get the ema from binance. If I manage to match them up after 5 minute everything is different\

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `onCandlestickEvent` is not just called when a candle is completed, but actually multiple times per minute (every 2 seconds or so). The data that you are receiving in the `response` spans the time from when the candle is opened until the event time of the response, whether the candle is completed or not.

To see what I mean, you could replace the `System.out()` statement in your `startCandlestickEventStreaming` method with the following:

```
System.out.println(response.getOpenTime() + ";" +
    response.getEventTime() + ";" +
    response.getCloseTime());
```

You will see that the close time of the candle actually lies in the future.

In order to update your EMA correctly, you will have to wait until the candle has actually been completed. You could store the open time of the tentative candle in a member variable, check if it has changed since the last time `onCandlestickEvent` was called, and then update your EMA with the final close value of the candle:

```
client.onCandlestickEvent(symbol.toLowerCase(), interval, response -> {
    Long openTime = response.getOpenTime(); 
    Candlestick updateCandlestick = candlesticksCache.get(openTime);
    if (updateCandlestick == null)
    {
        // new candlestick
        updateCandlestick = new Candlestick();
    }

    // update candlestick with the stream data
    ...
    
    // Store the updated candlestick in the cache
    candlesticksCache.put(openTime, updateCandlestick);

    if (openTime > m_LastOpenTime)
    {
        // need to get the close of the PREVIOUS candle
        Candlestick previousCandle = candlesticksCache.get(m_LastOpenTime);
        double closingPrice = Double.valueOf(previousCandle.getClose());
        
        EMA_10.update(closingPrice);
        EMA_20.update(closingPrice);

        System.out.println(StringUtil.replacePlaceholders("Closing price: %1 | EMA(10): %2 - EMA(20): %3", response.getClose(),
                                                        DecimalFormat.format(EMA_10.get(), "#.#####"),
                                                        DecimalFormat.format(EMA_20.get(), "#.#####")));

        m_LastOpenTime = openTime;
    }
});
```

You'll probably get an exception on the first response, because there are no candles on the stack yet and we don't have a `m_LastOpenTime`. You could get the current server time before calling `client.onCandlestickEvent()`:

```
private void startCandlestickEventStreaming(String symbol, CandlestickInterval interval)
{
    BinanceApiClientFactory factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance();
    BinanceApiWebSocketClient client = factory.newWebSocketClient();

    BinanceApiRestClient restClient = factory.newRestClient();
    m_LastOpenTime = restClient.getServerTime();

    client.onCandlestickEvent(symbol.toLowerCase(), interval, response -> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there's actually a much simpler way than my other answer. I'm leaving that one up, however, because it could still be relevant for dealing with a dodgy connection where you can't necessarily rely on always getting the final candlestick with your `response`.

The `response.getBarFinal())` method allows for testing whether the response you have received is the final candlestick or if it is just an intermediate one. If you change your code as follows, your EMA will only get updated with the final close value of the candle as it should be:

```
if (response.getBarFinal())
{
    double closingPrice = Double.valueOf(updateCandlestick.getClose());
    EMA_10.update(closingPrice);
    EMA_20.update(closingPrice);
    
    System.out.println(StringUtil.replacePlaceholders("Closing price: %1 | EMA(10): %2 - EMA(20): %3", response.getClose(),
            DecimalFormat.format(EMA_10.get(), "#.#####"),
            DecimalFormat.format(EMA_20.get(), "#.#####")));

}
```